# Working with inheritance

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, generics, inheritance

I am currently working on an app which has used inheritance in one scenario. But now I have an  task where I need to return more than one viewmodel from my model builder. I will describe below:

In my controller method we have kept it light and used model builders.

```
public ViewResult Summary(ReportArgs args)
{
    return View<SomeBuilder>(args);
}
```

This then hits the builder method which inherits from a base class.

```
public class SomeBuilder : NewBuilder<TaskVM, Task> {}
```

Then the NewBuilder has the following implementation:

```
public class NewBuilder<TModel, TItem> : ReportBuilder where TModel : SomeReportVM<TItem>, new() where TItem : ReportItem
{
    public override ReportVM Build(ReportArgs args)
    {
       /* Some code to get roles here */               
        return new TModel
        {
            FeedbackModel = FeedbackBuilder.Build(inputGrid.Report.Id),

        };                       
    }
}
```

What I need to do is return a different VM from the NewBuilder controller but struggling to finding the best way to do this?

I cannot return an InvalidVM as I pass in TaskVM. Just to make people aware this is being used by several views to a different VM and entity class would be passed in?

Comment: So you want to change "TaskVM" into something else? And whats a VM in your context?

Comment: Not sure if I undenrstood correctly - did you mean that an instance of `NewBuilder<TaskVM, Task>` should return something else than `TaskVM` (perhaps a class inheriting from `TaskVM`)

Comment: Hi Ivalyo in regards to your comment I need to return a different VM(ViewModel). In my case it would be a viewmodel called InvalidVM. So in my view i wqould use DisplayFor() and create the relevant displaytemplates.

Comment: Assuming that `ReportBuilder` is of type `NewBuilder<ReportVM, Report>`, it seems like you are trying to put together some sort of multiple-inheritance, with instances of `NewBuilder` being both `ReportBuilder` and `NewBuilder<T, U>`. This will not work. The answer is to look at implementing an interface instead of inheriting a base class.

Comment: Thanks Keith. You are correct. This has been implemented prior to me working on the application. But I understand why it was done with multiple inheritance. Now requirements have changed so we need to check some authorisation rules and return a invalidVM which then returns a view with the relevant restricted message to the user.

Comment: I don't really understand your code. But I noticed your use of generics. I generally try to avoid using generics when inheritance should be used. I know it is easier with generics, but if you re-designed your code to work with inheritance instead of generics, it would become much clearer where should the intended change be.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Can you clarify your code? What class does the `Summary` method belong to? I'm assuming your `View<SomeBuilder>` method calls `Build` on an instance of `SomeBuilder`. Is that correct?

Comment: "I cannot return an InvalidVM as I pass in TaskVM" Is return type(output) dependant on what you pass in (input)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class EnhancedBuilder<TModel, TItem, TInvalidModel> : NewBuilder<TModel, TItem>
    where TModel : SomeReportVM<TItem>, new()
    where TItem : ReportItem
    where TInvalidModel : SomeReportVM<TItem>, new() // Made an assumption here.
    // It would likely be wise to create an InvalidVM base class to handle common
    // issues such as roles, and defer the rest to child builders.
{
    public override ReportVM Build(ReportArgs args)
    {
       /* Some code to get roles here */   

        if( ** validation code fails ** ) 
        {
            return new TInvalidModel
            {
            }
        }

        return new TModel
        {
            FeedbackModel = FeedbackBuilder.Build(inputGrid.Report.Id),

        };                       
    }
}
```

Then your SomeBuilder will look bit different.

```
public class SomeBuilder<TInvalidVM> : NewBuilder<TaskVM, Task, TInvalidVM>
    where TInvalidVM : SomeReportVM<TItem>, new()
{
}
```

And finally calling it:

```
public ViewResult Summary(ReportArgs args)
{
    return View<SomeBuilder<MyInvalidVM>>(args);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is invalid, throw an error and catch it up stream (in your first code block above, for example) and render the invalid view model or handle however you'd like.  Would that work in your scenario?